# How to identify error in a particular file while checksum verification (which file having problem while verification) in shell script

Tags: shell, hashsum

I have two files on ftp location in csv.gz format and their checksum is in .csv.gz.md5 format. I am copying this file in my local system. I am generating check sum for it through **md5sum**. Now I am comparing it against the copied file.

Now I want to identify any **error** in a file if there is one and also which file is having an **error**.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `csv.gz.md5` was generated using `md5sum csv.gz > csv.gz.md5`, then you can check using `md5sum -c cvs.gz.md5`.

```
$ echo Hello World > something.abc
$ md5sum something.abc > something.abc.md5
$ md5sum -c something.abc.md5 && echo YAY || echo NAY
something.abc: OK
YAY
$ echo Garbage >> something.abc
$ md5sum -c something.abc.md5 && echo YAY || echo NAY
something.abc: FAILED
md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
NAY
```